how to write polyquine program for both python and lua?
A polyquine is a program that is valid in multiple programming languages. The task is to write a polyquine that can switch between Python and Lua.
The program should take a single integer argument n.
In Python: If n is even, print "Even in Python". If n is odd, print "Odd in Python".
In Lua: If n is even, print "Even in Lua". If n is odd, print "Odd in Lua".
The program should be valid syntax in both languages and produce the correct output when run with a Python interpreter or a Lua interpreter.
_=1
n=...
_=1

if n==nil then n=int(input()) end
if n%2==0 then print("Even in "..(_ and "Python" or "Lua")) else print("Odd in "..(_ and "Python" or "Lua")) end


i tried various other progrAams too but couldn't compile in both the compilers

Is this the complete code, the visual inspection shows there are some syntactical problems

Both languages have differences in syntax and because of that, it's somewhat difficult to write a code that can be compiled by both the compilers.
I tried various other codes, but none of them worked.

It sounds like you want to write a polyglot program, not a polyquine. A polyquine would have to be a quine - it would have to output its own source code.

You need to be very familiar with the syntax of both languages to write a polyglot. Hint: One useful trick is to use comments. --expr is a double negation of expr in Python, but a comment in Lua. #expr is the length of expr in Lua, but a comment in Python. That way you can write expressions which only run in one of the respective languages. Now figure out how to write your program as an expression syntactically (hint: you can either use load / eval, or actually write expression-oriented code).

One boring solution would be
n = 1

--1; """
print((n % 2 == 0 and "Even" or "Odd") .. " in Lua")
--1; """


--1; print(("Even" if n % 2 == 0 else "Odd") + " in Python")

--1; is a safe comment for Lua, and within Python it was easier to "disable" Lua code by wrapping it into a multi line string.
But I feel like this question belongs into https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
